# php ORM - RedBean in production?

Tags: php, database, orm

I would like to know how many of you are using RedBean ORM in your php production sites and what is your experience with it (reliability, speed, problems (if any),...)?

Thank You.

Comment: As I've been digging into it, the to most used ORMs in the PHP world are Propel and Doctrine, so I think that you wont get many responses...

Comment: I know about doctrine, doctrine 2, propel,... but i want users opinions/expirience with RedBean.

Comment: If anyone has integrated this into Lithium (Li3), any pointers would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Might want to do some thorough benchmarking tests on redbean you might want to take a look at http://groups.google.com/group/redbeanorm/browse_thread/thread/093eee3a3ac19732/83d3a3d312a5bca0?lnk=raot&fwc=1&pli=1

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I wrote RedBean because I was dissappointed in Doctrine. I have used both Propel and Doctrine but I felt unproductive.

We use RedBean for several projects and it performs well. Actually RedBean is not a really 'fat' orm layer, so it's quite easy to optimize (almost all SQL is stored in one class; the query writer). It does not have a query parser, a customized SQL language or a query builder. If you want to improve performance even more you can decide to use plain SQL instead and use the convertToBeans-option afterwards.

Comment: How so? I've been working with Doctrine 1.2 in a very big project (on my own) and I'm already 50% done in 15 days. What was it about Doctrine that dissappointed you?

Comment: I found it a very counter-intuitive library and I did not like the to switch back and foward between phpmyadmin or a cli-generator and my code. I am a very agile coder, I like to prototype and I was looking for a way to 'design the schema in an evolutionary way'. Of course this is highly subjective and I wont say Doctrine is a bad product. I just did not like it and that is why I crafted my own.

Comment: Definitely, i have to spend more time with RedBean, before any conclusions and before i maka a move. There is nothing wrong with Doctrine (2), respect and love (it is a VERY mighty tool), it's just that with my first "bean" i asked myself: Why am i not using RedBean? My imagination went wild and i thought, just for a second: "This is how all this should work." It was love at first sight :) at least from developer experience point of view. Doctrine (2) is, de facto, php orm standard and i wanted to know how RedBean could be compared with, for example, Doctrine (2) in such enviroment.

Comment: I just don't have enough information,  experience, feedback, time, tests, ...or you can simply say that i don't have enough balls, to use RedBean in production. So, i wanted to make a bit of a shortcut with this question but ... i can't tell about RedBean i can just cross my fingers for RedBean and start a little app that uses RedBean. The app will tell me and my wife will kill me :) so... For now, thank you Gabor de Mooij.

Comment: I use RedBean on a small-to-medium traffic website and it behaves wonderful. I wrote my own wrapper around it to make model classes for my DB, but apart from that everything was already there. It works just as I want it to, so I think I'll stick with it in my later projects as well.

Comment: @Gabor de Mooij - Redbean is awesome! Thanks for writing it. Just like predrag, I just fell in love thinking "this is how it should work".

Comment: @Gabor de Mooij - Thanks for RedBean! I use Codeigniter and I'm trying to understand, how can FUSE autoload from "Codeigniter/application/models" Path. So that, I can place models inside the default CI models path.

Comment: Tried Doctrine but I spent more time learning how to use it than really using it. Redbean is perfect for my needs, light, easy to learn (no learning really) and has exactly the functionality I need, no less, no more. I had used it already in two production apps with absolutely no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Heej,
I am using it in an website I am working on. I have integrated it with CodeIgniter and it works perfect. I haven't anything I couldn't do with it.

Karens

Comment: Thank you Karens. I have already made a small 3 table testing blog app with CI and RedBean. More details would be very helpful.

Comment: See here how to integrate CI with Redbean:
http://www.creolab.hr/2009/11/integration-of-redbean-orm-with-codeigniter/

Actually you use Models from Redbean and Controllers and Views from CodeIgniter

Comment: I already integrated it. So, would you use RedBean for a high traffic commercial document management application?

Comment: Actually yes. Redbean has been tested very well so the chance you find a bug is extremely small. And if you find one, they will be fixed very fast.

You should give it a try and won't regret it.

Comment: I would like to know, how to make RedBeanPhp FUSE, to load from "CODEIGNITER2.0.2/application/models" ? Tks